# Test image load event Angular 5

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm working with angular 5 developing some generic directives for my project and i have a problem with the image animation directive; the code for this one is the following

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[appImageAnimation]'
})
export class ImageAnimationDirective implements OnInit {

    image;
    dimensions;

    constructor(private elem: ElementRef) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.image = this.elem.nativeElement;
    }

    @HostListener('load')
    onImageLoad() {
        console.log('Image loaded!');
        this.dimensions = {
            width: this.image.naturalWidth,
            height: this.image.naturalHeight
        }
    }
}
```

I need to test the onImageLoad method that is triggered by image load event, i have the following test file

```
import { Component, DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { TestBed, ComponentFixture} from '@angular/core/testing';

import { ImageAnimationDirective } from './image-animation.directive';

@Component({
    template: `
        <div className="cont-test-img">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/450/?random"
                appImageAnimation />
        </div>
    `
})
class ImageTestComponent {
    constructor() {}
}

describe('ImageAnimationDirective', () => {
    let component: ImageTestComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<ImageTestComponent>;
    let debugElement: DebugElement;
    let directive: ImageAnimationDirective;
    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [ImageTestComponent, ImageAnimationDirective]
        });
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ImageTestComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
    });

    it('should get dimensions', () => {
        debugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(ImageAnimationDirective));
        directive = debugElement.injector.get(ImageAnimationDirective);
        spyOn(directive, 'onImageLoad').and.callThrough();
        expect(directive.dimensions.width).not.toEqual(0);
    });

});
```

But this test failed, i don't know what is missing, or what is the best way to execute the test validation when the image in the `ImageTestComponent` is loaded

I'm using **PhantomJS 2.1.1** as a test browser.

I'll appreciate your help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was testing similar functionality recently and first I decided against loading images from an API as the http call is more error-prone than loading a static test image.

To load static images, first you need to configure karma (I assume you have in your testing setup) to serve the image by modifying `karma.conf.js`and adding

```
files: [
  { pattern: './<PATH_TO_IMAGE_DIR>/**', watched: false, included:false, nocache:false, served:true }
]
```

then serving the image in your test case by appending `/base` before the image directory specified above and of course append the image file itself. Your spec has to be asynchronous using jasmine `done` function; something like this:

```
it('should get dimensions', (done) => {
    debugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(ImageAnimationDirective));
    directive = debugElement.injector.get(ImageAnimationDirective);
    fixture.detectChanges()

    // wait for a short time to make sure image is requested
    setTimeout(() => {
        expect(directive.dimensions.width).not.toEqual(0);
        done();
    }, 200);
});
```

if you decide against serving a static image then maybe the interval needs to be a bit more. I didn't test this but it should work